# My css.php file is being ignored by the browser

Tags: php, css, magento

I have this file:

```
<link src="http://mysite.com/theme/skin/frontend/default/beckin/css/options.css.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Which shows in the source code. Also when I click on the link in the source code it shows the css as it should. However, the browser is not using this file and it doesn't show up in the Firefox inspector.

What can I do to get the browser to use this css file?

BTW: This is for a custom extension that allows you to change the theme colors. Again, the file is working properly but the browser ignores it ??

Thanks!

I posted this here b/c I thought a good php and css expert might know the answer to this.

Comment: is there a reason why you are not making the file static .css?

Comment: @Lix He probably doesn't own `mysite.com`. ;) It's just a placeholder for a real address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the script sends valid Content-Type HTTP header:

```
header("Content-Type: text/css");
```

Comment: That is what I was missing! Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

It's not "src" it is "href".

```
 <link href="http://mysite.com/theme/skin/frontend/default/beckin/css/options.css.php"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Thanks. Yah I had the href at first but it wasn't working so I tried the other route to no avail either. I was missing the valid http header :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common error to make :) You should use 'href' atribute instead of 'src' to specify file's location.